# Laravel - A Model for a 3rd Party API?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm working on an iphone app which uses a Laravel backend for the API.  At some point, there will be [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/?hl=en) integration (or a similar service).

In my application, I'll need to store relationships between Users and Places, which is many-to-many.  However because 'Places' are not represented by an Eloquent model (but by Google's API), how do I create this relationship?  Do I need to create a wrapper for the Google Places API?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it.

All your models extend from the base [Eloquent ORM model class](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php) which means it is possible to overwrite the finders/getters/setters etc in your extended class.

Your Google Place model is a special case that is it does not depend on the database but on the Google Places API.

Therefore, you will need to overwrite base Eloquent model methods for the Google Places model.

For example:

```
class GooglePlace extends Eloquent{
    /**
     * Find a model by its primary key or return new static.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|static
     */
    public static function findOrNew($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
       # we do not need Eloquent's database based implementation
       # api code to get Google Place using $id 
       # perhaps use $columns to get only specific fields about the place
       # from the API?
    }
}
```

Then on, you only need to link the user with the place in the pivot table using the Google Place ID.

Answer (score 1):

To provider complexe implementation between an API and a Eloquent Model transparency. I recommand that you use https://github.com/CristalTeam/php-api-wrapper.

`cristal/php-api-wrapper`, you can create Models for your APIs and you have a query builder specifically adapted to API requests. You can use advanced Laravel features like Route Binding and relationships between an Eloquent model and a model of this package.

Answer (score 0):

I think make a model for a 3rd party is not relevant because it's not the role of eloquent to serve and consume API's.
Otherwise i suggest you to make a service:

- Create a folder app/Service
- Create a class inside with the good namespace
- Create your own functions. you can create a config file and use it with Env variables to store credentials
- Finally call your service in your controller, before declare it in the input of the function and laravel will resolve it automatically.

`public function test(MyService $service)`